# Why Capybara / Rspec can't find the button in Sweet Alert Modal but have_selector return true?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

This is a Rspec feature.

```
given (:send_selector){ 'button.confirm'}

feature "when talent has not applied." do
  given (:apply_button) { find('button[data-selector="offer-apply-button"]') }
  before(:each)         { visit offer_path(offer.id)                         }

  scenario "Talent applies to offer with default cv", js: true do
    apply_button.click
    expect(page).to have_selector(send_selector)
    find_button(send_selector).click
    wait_for_ajax
    # other expectations
  end
end
```

It passes the expectation to have the selector but then it throws the error

```
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find button "button.confirm"
```

Pointing to the line with `find_button(send_selector).click`

I Also tried using `page.find_button(send_selector).click`
and `find_button(send_selector).trigger('click')` but the first still throws the error and the second seems to do nothing because the controller responsible for the action is never called and the modal is still there when I take a screenshot in the next line.

I run the poltergeist debugger and the html is present on the page.

[image: html code from the poltergeist debugger]

This is the modal as seen by capybara (using `save_screenshot()` method)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `find_button` doesn't take a CSS selector -http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Finders#find_button-instance_method - it takes the name, id, title, or text content of the button (the same as `click_button` and 'have_button' takes).

In your answer the `sleep 1` had nothing to do with solving the issue, it was fixed because you swapped from `find_button` to `find` which does take a CSS selector

Comment: Hi Thomas, you are right, the find_button does not take a css selector. Even though, I run the test I posted in the answer this time without `sleep 1` and failed.

Comment: @juliangonzalez If it's the same error then it probably means you need to increase Capybara.default_max_wait_time by a couple of seconds.  However, if it's a different error (something about mouse click would hit a different element) then it's because the modal is still animating, and you will either need the sleep  or better yet disable animations in test mode, which will speed up your tests and prevent some potential flakiness

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has the same problem, it works just fine adding a little sleep after the modal shows up. This behavior is still strange since the expectation says the selector is alredy there. Even `have_selector(send_selector, visible: true).present?` returns true.

```
scenario "Talent applies to offer with default cv", js: true do
  apply_button.click
  expect(page).to have_selector(send_selector)
  sleep 1                                        <<--  THIS SOLVED THE PROBLEM
  find(send_selector).click
  wait_for_ajax
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced that issue when using sweetalert2 and I solved it in feature spec as below. (it worked)

```
scenario 'destroy a company', js: true do
    within('.shadow.company-info') do
        find('a[data-behavior="delete"]').click
        wait_for_ajax
        within(page.document.find(:css, '.swal2-buttonswrapper')) do
            find(:css, '.swal2-confirm').click
            wait_for_ajax
            expect(page.document).to have_content I18n.t('delete.success')
        end
    end
end
```